# python asking age and comparing to eli statements

Tags: python

New to programming and starting on the book automate the boring stuff in the book there is a part of code that mentions to ask a person's name and if it is not a specific name to check the person's age and depending on the age one of three things happens. The problem is the book doesn't go over the input part of it. I can get the name okay but I cannot get it to allow me to input the age as an integer and then match those integers against my elif statements. What am I doing wrong, note that without the  if age < int(12) I am told that you cannot compare str and int values and the code errors out. Any help is greatly appreciate it.

```
    print('What is your name?')
    name=input()
    if name == 'Alice':
       print('Hi,Alice.')
    elif name != 'Alice':
        print('How old you is?????')
        age=input()
        int(age)
        age=int(age)
  if age < int(12):
    print('You are not Alice,kiddo.')
 elif age > int(2000):
    print('Unlike you, Alice is not an undead, immortal vampire.')
 elif age > 100:
    print('You are not Alice, grannie.')
```

Comment: Other than indentation issues, the code works fine. What's not working for you? What is the exact error message and traceback?

Comment: After asking my age no matter what I put in the next line is >>>   and not any of the elif choices.

Comment: I just realized I only give a statement for if the age is less than 12 or greater than 100 or 2000, and nothing for if it is between 12 or 100 I think this may have caused some of my issues.

Answer (score 0):

The input function returns a string. To convert the result put the int() function like you see in the following code

```
print('What is your name?')
name=input()
if name == 'Alice':
    print('Hi,Alice.')
    age = 12
elif name != 'Alice':
    print('How old you is?????')
    age=int(input())
if age < 12:
    print('You are not Alice,kiddo.')
elif age > 2000:
    print('Unlike you, Alice is not an undead, immortal vampire.')
elif age > 100:
    print('You eare not Alice, grannie.')
```

Comment: So when I use this code, no matter the name I put in I am being asked to give an age. Any number I put in does not bring up any of the three eli choices.

Comment: I apologize I forgot that the Alice has to be capital A. However the other part about the number not triggering one of the eli statements remains.

Comment: Actually nevermind playing with the code again this does work as intended. Thank you!

Comment: Now it will work... In the copy n paste I forget an indentation

Comment: Th age = int(input()) must be indented, four space towards right, I corrected it

Answer (score -1):

Consider using the raw_input() function for general input from users. There are some difference between raw_input() and input(), and raw_input() is what you need to get the input name.
raw_input([prompt]) -> string, read a string from standard input.
input([prompt]) -> value, Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).